# HTML annotation system to aid web UI test automation element/attribute references?

Tags: html, automation, automated-tests, ui-automation

Is there a system for annotating HTML for the purpose of identifying elements/attributes critical to web user interface test automation (by Selenium, HTMLUnit, Watir, Sahi, etc.)? The system might be a standard or library. The annotations might for example be implemented as HTML data attributes which reference simply an attribute name, an XPath expression, or CSS selector that needs to exist and remain consistent for test automation purposes. If identified attributes/elements change, test automation may break, so developers should not change them without coordinating with those responsible for automation. So the annotations are at the very least a visual cue to developers.

But beyond that, perhaps an "enforcer" part of the system (continuous integration plugin, CLI, or perhaps JavaScript library on the same page) would enforce the annotations to some degree, failing quickly and clearly if certain conditions are not satisfied. Perhaps the identified attribute/XPath/selector must exist and reference the same element that defines the annotation.  The enforcer can also gather all the annotations and perhaps report the full list of them on each page of a web application, for diff notification purposes.

I may have some details not well worked out, but hopefully the gist of what I'm looking for makes sense. A free license would be handy but not absolutely necessary.

Does something like this exist?

A helpful answer might also be:

- There's a better way to address your underlying need (with explanation).
- We tried implementing this and it's not worth it; here's why.

**Motivation:** Web user interface tests can be sensitive to changes to HTML elements and attributes. The tests often run in an integration testing job or phase which may be significantly later than the build or unit tests. It would be nice to catch some of the potential mismatches between UI elements and test expectations earlier, in the build or unit test phase, and also to provide a test automation engineer more information to indicate what may be a bug in a test vs. a bug in the product under test.

Answer (score 2):

As you say:

> The annotations might for example be implemented as HTML data attributes

This is the way people are going with HTML5 as it enables us to pass control over to our QA automation teams and lets development teams ignore their concerns (changing an ID on an element would affect their testing).

So, an HTML element might look like (a relatively contrived example):

```
<div id="button" data-test-attribute="submit"></div>
```

Most selectors used by these libraries use CSS-oriented selections, making selecting the above eay. There are a number of articles that have begun to address this.

A [really brief one](https://www.utest.com/articles/data-qa-attribute-a-better-way-to-select-elements-for-ui-test-automation) I like states:

> ID’s and also css class names have another purpose than for the usage
>   in UI automated tests. Css classes are primarily used to style
>   elements and they also can get uglified on the production page. ID’s
>   have also another purpose and can also sometimes just change or they
>   are not get implemented because they interfere with other functions on
>   the page.

It seems another part of your question is concerned about *enforcement*. This would be relatively simple to integrate into your build process with a hand-spun thing using something like Node.js and webpack (might increase your build time, considerably - but certainly possible).